# How to fix 'TypeError: unlink() missing 1 required positional argument: \'values\'\n''

Tags: python, api, odoo, odoo-11

Im using Python 3.6 and xmlrpc to unlink all canceled Sale orders in odoo 11 CE but im still getting this error:

```
odoo11/odoo/api.py", line 690, in call_kw_multi\n    result = method(recs, args, *kwargs)\nTypeError: unlink() missing 1 required positional argument: \'values\'\n'>
```

ive also tried somehting like:

```
            , [[sale_id]])
```

instead of:

```
            , [sale_id])
```

heres my code:

```
import xmlrpc.client

class Odoo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.DATA = "DB"
        self.USER = "USER"
        self.PASS = "PASS"
        self.PORT = "8069"
        self.URL = "http://localhost"
        self.URL_COMMON = "{}:{}/xmlrpc/2/common".format(
            self.URL, self.PORT)
        self.URL_OBJECT = "{}:{}/xmlrpc/2/object".format(
            self.URL, self.PORT)
    def authenticateOdoo(self):
        self.ODOO_COMMON = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(self.URL_COMMON)
        self.ODOO_OBJECT = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(self.URL_OBJECT)
        self.UID = self.ODOO_COMMON.authenticate(
            self.DATA
            , self.USER
            , self.PASS
            , {})
def main():
    od = Odoo()
    od.authenticateOdoo()
    sale_ids = od.ODOO_OBJECT.execute_kw(od.DATA, od.UID, od.PASS, 'sale.order', 'search', [[("state", "=", "cancel")]])
    od.ODOO_OBJECT.execute_kw(od.DATA, od.UID, od.PASS, 'sale.order', 'unlink', [sale_ids])
    print(od.UID)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide the full error (backtrace) in a readable way. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The Odoo you're trying to call is your Odoo ? And if is it true, have you override the method unlink of sale.order?

Comment: im trying to unlink all sale.order by executing python script above for my local running odoo server. what youre meaning with "override"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is python error,  you called a `method` that is defined with positional argument `values` without argument. The problem here the unlink method of a Model don't accept any arguement.

So check your costum addons where did you inherit the `sale.order` model and you override the `unlink` method and remove `values` argument.

Look for this method in your odoo instance and remove `values` arguement restart the server and everything will be fine.

```
   _inherit = 'sale.order'

  ......
  ......

   @api.multi
   def unlink(values):
```